# Update Terminal Output Node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, output

I've been working on some problems on [projecteuler.net](https://projecteuler.net/archives), and am programming functions and algorithms to solve these problems in mostly JavaScript (ran in the Node.js environment).

In many of these problems I am going through many thousand different numbers, and I would like to show (in the terminal output) which number it is currently on. I don't want it to just keep writing new lines, but just update the existing line... Is there a way to do this in JavaScript? Possibly with the help of any Node modules?

I know there is a way to clear the console, and so I could just have it clear it and then write the number again, but that would also clear the previous output that I still want to show...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into ANSI escape codes if you want to do this by hand, or look into one of the many Node.js libraries. Search keyword is  `ANSI escape codes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this suffices?

```js
import readline from 'readline';

function clearLine() {
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
  readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
}

let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  clearLine();
  process.stdout.write(String(counter++));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It seems to work how I want it... One question... do you know what the average execution time of that is?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck Sorry, I do not(

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Thank you for your answer, it does help a lot!